# Previous versions of an artifact in Azure Artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I am new to Azure Devops. I want to use Azure artifact to publish my build artifacts there so that we can use them as a Maven dependency. The issue I am facing is when I deploy a newer version of my artifact, it overrides the previous version. This can lead to issues for the user of my artifacts.

Is there any specific settings using which I can change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description you are using the Azure Artifact feed, right?

If it is, then the old version of packages will not be overwritten by the new versions. By default we can see the latest version of packages in the feed home page. However we can click the specific package, then switch to the `Versions` tab to check the old versions of that package.

Then you can reference the specific version of the packages in your project.

[image]